# How can I make my element clickable for Vimium?

Tags: html, vimium

I'm using Vimium on Firefox and Chrome and it helps me a lot https://github.com/philc/vimium

I noticed that some divs can be clicked and I found that `class='demo-button'` is one of them

```
<div class='demo-button'>demo-button</div>
<div class='demobutton'>demobutton</div>
<div class='demobuttonnn'>demobuttonn</div>
<div class='demobutto'>demobutto</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of Vimium links https://jsfiddle.net/qnvujfs6/

[image]

As you can see, only the last div `demobutto` can not be clicked using Vimium. I tried to search Vimium source for `demo-button` or `demobutton` but no results.

Does anyone have an idea why there is a difference between this demo button `div`-s ?

I want to be able to click on some generated elements using bootstrap plugins, for example [Bootstrap Toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/). Here is code for two toggles, but only second one can be clicked because it contains `demo-button` class

https://codepen.io/duleorlovic/pen/VqWaEg

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first three are clickable because the `class` attribute contains the word "button" ([See source](https://github.com/philc/vimium/blob/881a6fdc3644f55fc02ad56454203f654cc76618/content_scripts/link_hints.coffee#L717)).

For usability purposes it preferred to simply use the elements that are meant to do that job. For instance anchors (`<a>`) and buttons (`<button>`).

But if that is not possible (which seems to be the case here) you can also add the `role` attribute to the element. Elements with the attribute `role` with one of the following values will also be considered clickable:

- button
- tab
- link
- checkbox
- menuitem
- menuitemcheckbox
- menuitemradio

([Source](https://github.com/philc/vimium/blob/881a6fdc3644f55fc02ad56454203f654cc76618/content_scripts/link_hints.coffee#L657))

So if your `div` elements represent check boxes, your code would look like this:

```html
<div class="demo-button" role="checkbox">demo-button</div>
<div class="demobutton" role="checkbox">demobutton</div>
<div class="demobuttonnn" role="checkbox">demobuttonn</div>
<div class="demobutto" role="checkbox">demobutto</div>
```

In this case you are not depending on specific class names, [which are by the extension considered "as unreliable"](https://github.com/philc/vimium/blob/881a6fdc3644f55fc02ad56454203f654cc76618/content_scripts/link_hints.coffee#L717).

Comment: Great, so I can keep fingers on my keyboard :) I will use class names since that is provided as an option to plugins, and I will submit pull requests to add those `role` attributes. Btw on this plugin demo https://stephanwagner.me/jBox I discovered that I can click on divs, quite accidentally because, as you explained, it contains 'button' in the class name.